# slf4j,change logger or add appender at runtime

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, slf4j, interceptor

I'm using SLF4J for logging (with Log4J).
The used appender is configured using an xml.

```xml
<appender name="business" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/business.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%t] %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<category name="BusinessLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="business" />
</category>
```

The log process is called in an interceptor. Now, I'm trying to test the output of the log. I call the logger at runtime using:

```
private static final Logger BUSINESS_LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("BusinessLogger");
```

In order to test the log (using junit), the output of the log needs to be saved somewhere as a variable. I have an idea about creating a custom appender which saves the last log into variable, but I can't seem to add an appender or change the appender because the Logger class in slf4j is an interface. Does anyone maybe know any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I kind of solved it with the help from alterfox.

When I called the logger using slf4j:

```
private static final Logger BUSINESS_LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("BusinessLogger");
```

It returns me an implementation of the logger adapter from slf4j which doesn't have the add appender method. So I called the logger using log4j Logger class

```
private static final Logger BUSINESS_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("BusinessLogger")
```

Even though the class names are "Logger", they are from different package. The latter one, which is Log4J method, returns the actual Logger object from Log4J. Then the addAppender method becomes available. Well, I tried this, and it doesn't work (except it does). The thing is, I forgot to set the log level. So after adding the appender, I set the log level and then I see the logs coming through the second appender.

Comment: If your code is using slf4j directly (LoggerFactory.getLogger()), this will fail, as you are adding the handler to log4j, which goes unused if slf4j is called directly.

Answer (score 3):

slf4j is just a facade on the top of log4j/log4j2/logback. 
Once you declare the slf4j logger object:

```
private static final Logger BUSINESS_LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("BusinessLogger");
```

You can add your log4j appender using log4j LogManager.

`LogManager.getLogger("BusinessLogger").addAppender(consoleAppender);`

Answer (score 2):

This may seem simple but I found when I encountered this error I had forgotten to place the binder package in my POM for my application.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Without this import, I was getting the error `org.apache.log4j.Logger.addAppender() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.log4j.FileAppender)`. If the log4j classes aren't setup properly, make sure to check the logging implementation.

Comment: This brings mockito-core 3.x, if you have a lower version, it might give hard times debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use console appender, and redirect your console output. See this post for more details: [Redirect console output to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java)

Also, you can use your file appender, and then read the log from the file, when you need to inspect it.

And for the end, take a look if this can be of some help to you: [PropertyConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html)

Comment: Yes, I know about that. But is there a way to add an appender to slf4j logger instance at runtime?

Comment: @Rowanto I think that you need to work with concrete implementation for that. E.g. Logger.getLogger("BusinessLogger").addAppender(...), where Logger is from org.apache.log4j. Think about whether your example requires adding _at runtime_ at all.

Comment: I don't want the custom appender to run at production. It's just, when testing with junit, I want to attach a custom appender in the test, so that I can test the log output. I have also tried calling the object directly, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, just tried it again really quickly, it works indeed. I just forgot to set the log level.. :|
Thanks!

Comment: @Rowanto So what is your solution? What is that object you are calling directly?

Comment: Instead of calling the logger through slf4j which returns an implementation of slf4j interface 'LoggerFactory.getLogger("BusinessLogger");', I called the object directly using log4j Logger.getLogger("BusinessLogger");