# How can I print output from a servlet onto JSP page using method with return type as void

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am developing a web application where i use various string manipulation methods with return types as strings or list from a Java Class. I invoke these methods in my servlet and using JSTL, i am successfully able to print the output to my JSP page. So, no issues with JSTL syntax or basic Servlet-JSP interaction. Here is an example:

My base class that has all these functions:

```
public class MethodClass {
// Skipping unwanted code and only providing example
    public static List<String> method1 (String input) {
         // Returns List of Strings
    }
    public static String method2 (String input) {
        // Returns a string
    }
    public static void method3 (String input) {
       // This method has to print text on console. I can't redirect that to a String.
       System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Below is my Servlet code (relevant snippet only)

```
            listMethod1 = MethodClass.method1(input);
            request.setAttribute("Myresults", listMethod1);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/results.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And in my JSP, I am using the following:

```
<c:forEach items="${Myresults}" var="result">       
    <tr>
        <td>${result.frameNum}</td>
        <td>${result.number}</td>
        <td>${result.name}</td>
        <td>${result.length}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

So far no issues. My question is how do I print the output from method3 into a text area. AFAIK, out.println function of response.getWriter() can be used to print directly on the JSP without any provision for printing to a certain field like text area or text box of a certain JSP file. Is there any other approach that I can follow where I can somehow redirect the output of a void method that prints on the console to a String and then use that String similar to the example that I provided above to display output.

Comment: Your method3 writes to System.out. Not to the response writer. How about rewriting this method to return a String instead of printing it to the console?

Comment: @JB Nizet, I tried that. I am using a third-party JAR file for this method which does not have any provision for returning a string.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're in a really bad situation. You could redirect System.out to another in-memory stream, but that would affect all the threads in the JVM which could also write unrelated values to System.out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a trick. Thanks again stackOverflow.

Here is the link: [Redirect console output to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java)

Here is the relevant code snippet that I used:

```
// Create a stream to hold the output
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
// IMPORTANT: Save the old System.out!
PrintStream old = System.out;
// Tell Java to use your special stream
System.setOut(ps);
// Print some output: goes to your special stream
System.out.println("Foofoofoo!");
// Put things back
System.out.flush();
System.setOut(old);
// Show what happened
System.out.println("Here: " + baos.toString());
```

Now your System.out output can be saved as a String and can be just used in the JSP normally with JSTL.

Comment: That's what I was referring to in my comment. But be aware that if another request (or even background threads of your server) is handled in parallel and happens to write to System.out, what it writes will also be inside the result. In short, what you have there won't work if you have more than one user using your application.