# Get content from outputstream

Tags: java, caching, output, outputstream

I am using a really old Java version and i am missing a lot of classes. The system runs on an embedded platform. There is a class to execute system commands, but the output from the command is discarded. Is there anyway to cache or get this output another way?

There is another java application that is not coded by us that we interact with. This application starts a test and output the results in the shell. We are not able to edit the source code of that application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you launch the command?  do you have the `java.lang.Process` class?

Comment: No, i don't have that one. This is a specific one for this system. I can't find any other execute methods.

The command is launched via a class called Ish. The method is Ish.execute():

public static int execute(String cmd) throws IOException.

The returned int is of no use

Comment: does your os include some sort of shell like `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: Nope, no shell like that

Comment: Does reflection work in this jvm?

Comment: Does not seems like that :/

Answer (score 0):

If the external app will run inside the same process, you can try to redirect `System.out` (using `System.setOut()`) before the call to the external application.

Comment: This sounds interesting. What do you suggest me to use instead?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java

However, i dont have the method setOut()

And i cant change system.out since its a final variable.

Comment: A `ByteArrayOutputStream`-backed `PrintStream` was my first choice too. What version of Java are you using? System.setOut() is there since 1.1. BTW, this only helps if your other app starts in the same process, not in a new one.

Comment: Using java with these options: target 1.1, source 1.3. This is some special java for this system.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to run system commands.

```
       ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
       Map env = pb.environment();
       env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
       env.remove("OTHERVAR");
       env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
       pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
       File log = new File("log");
       pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
       pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
       Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: The ProcessBuilder and Map classes does not exists. It's a really shitty OS.

Comment: ProcessBuilder class is in java since 1.5. If you want to use older than this another alternative is to use, java.lang.Runtime class. And how come Map is not there? java.util.Map is there since JDK 1.2. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Using java with these options: target 1.1, source 1.3. However, this is a special JVM for this specific system. Crappy like hell

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how desperate you are, you can manipulate the standard output of the launched process by adding a "shim" class.  Basically, create your own class with a main method which redirects stdout to your desired location (like some known file).

```
public class HackMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ... use reflection to hack System.out ...

    // invoke "real" main
    RealMainClass.main(args);
  }
}
```

Then add a jar with this class to the invoked process command line and call it instead like `java -cp <other_jars>:<hack_jar> HackMain [<args> ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a shell wrapper and you have access to the file system you can try to redirect the output of your command to a file and read it from there:

```
Ish.execute(fancyCommand + " > myfile.tmp");
InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/myfile.tmp"));
        int c;
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1){
            sb.append((char)c);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought about that, but the > to put it into a file does not exists.