# How to Store the Insert query of hibernate with session save method in String

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to know how to store the hibernate update query with model class and evict method in the string.

If we set the show_sql property to true, it displays the SQL query onside console, but my requirements like to store the insert query inside the DB. I want to store the query in string with parameter.

Following is the code.

```
final SessionFactory factoryNew =  configHibernate.configure().buildSessionFactory();
hibernateSession = factoryNew.openSession();
final Transaction insertSerialIdTransaction = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
                final GroupDevice addGroupDevice = new GroupDevice();
                addGroupDevice.setDeviceId(0);
                addGroupDevice.setSerialId(cut[0]);
                addGroupDevice.setOldMsata_password(oldMsataPassword);
                addGroupDevice.setIsNew(0);
                addGroupDevice.setDeviceStatus("staging");
                hibernateSession.save(addGroupDevice);
                hibernateSession.flush();
                insertSerialIdTransaction.commit();
```

Show the query on console like this: INSERT Into GroupDevice (DeviceId,SerialId,OldMsata_password, IsNew, DeviceStatus) values(0,"kdjhg65",0,"staging");

I want to store the above query in the string, how to store in the string.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate `show_sql` is printing directly to console (`System.out`), so you can capture that output by using the `System.setOut` method to change `System.out` to go to a `PrintStream` provided by you. If you create a `PrintStream` connected to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then you can capture the output as a `String`.

Look here:
[Redirect console output to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java)

Then you can easily do what you want to with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time. i got almost idea from your above link. from there i will do it. Thank you so much...:)

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept and upvote it ;)

Comment: oooppppsss, i don't have 15 reputation to upvote,sorry for right now, but whenever i got more than 15 reputation,it will be voted..:)