# Java: How to use console output for conditional statements

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, console

I'm writing a java program in Eclipse that runs gradle and unit tests. These tests output a bunch of information to the console. When a certain line comes up in the output I want to execute a certain method.

I would like to know if there is a way that I can scan the console output for a specific string, and when that string is found to execute my next method.

Basically I want an IF-THEN statement, while my program runs, that says `if(ConsoleString==TargetString), do(This)`.

Comment: Placed example code in code sample

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
if (input.equals("TargetString")) {
    doSomething();
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer to this here: 
[Redirect console output to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java)

I like the ConsoleOutputCapturer class by @Manasjyoti Sharma in the answer.