# How to get a string representation of DataFrame (as does Dataset.show)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need a useful string representation of a Spark dataframe. The one I get with `df.show` is great -- but I can't get that output as a string because the internal `showString` method called by `show` is private. Is there some way I can get a similar output without writing a method to duplicate this same functionality?

Comment: I wonder what is the rationale for making this method private?

Answer (score 11):

`showString` is simply [private[sql]](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L241) that means that the code to access it has to be in the same package, i.e. `org.apache.spark.sql`.

The trick is to create a helper object that does belong to the `org.apache.spark.sql` package, but the single method we're about to create is not `private` (at any level).

I usually mimic what an instance method does with the very first input parameter as the target and the input parameters to match the target method.

```
package org.apache.spark.sql
object AccessShowString {
  def showString[T](df: Dataset[T],
      _numRows: Int, truncate: Int = 20, vertical: Boolean = false): String = {
    df.showString(_numRows, truncate, vertical)
  }
}
```

**TIP** Use `paste -raw` to copy and paste the code in `spark-shell`.

Let's use `showString` then.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.AccessShowString.showString
val df = spark.range(10)
scala> println(showString(df, 10))
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+
```

Comment: error: object AccessShowString is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

Comment: @aName Did you define the helper object `AccessShowString` from the first code snippet section? What Spark environment do you use? spark-shell perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

If you really set on reusing existing code, you can access `showString` by reflection

```scala
scala> val df = spark.range(10)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> val showString = classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame].getDeclaredMethod("showString", classOf[Int], classOf[Int], classOf[Boolean])
showString: java.lang.reflect.Method = public java.lang.String org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(int,int,boolean)

scala> showString.setAccessible(true)

scala> showString.invoke(df, 10.asInstanceOf[Object], 20.asInstanceOf[Object], false.asInstanceOf[Object]).asInstanceOf[String]
res2: String =
"+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+
"
```