# How to do logging of spark Dataset printSchema in info/debug level in spark- java project

Tags: java, sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to covert my spark scala project into spark-java project.
I have a logging in scala as below

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    class ClassName{
      val logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ClassName")
      ...
      val dataframe1 = ....///read dataframe from text file.
      ...

      logger.debug("dataframe1.printSchema : \n " + dataframe1.printSchema; //this is working fine.
    }
```

Now I am trying to write it in java 1.8 as below

```
public class ClassName{

    public static final Logger logger  = oggerFactory.getLogger("ClassName"); 
      ...
     Dataset<Row> dataframe1 = ....///read dataframe from text file.
     ...

     logger.debug("dataframe1.printSchema : \n " + dataframe1.printSchema()); //this is not working 

}
```

I tried several ways but nothing worked to log printSchema in debug/info mode.

dataframe1.printSchema() // this actually returning void hence not able to append to string.

How actually logging is done spark-java production grade projects ?
What is the best approach I need to follow to log in debugging?

How to handle the above scenario? i.e. log.debug( dataframe1.printSchema() ) in java ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `df.schema.treeString`. This returns a string when compared to Unit() equivalent of `Void` in java returned by `df.printSchema`. This is true in Scala and I believe it is the same in Java.Let me know if that helps.

```
scala> val df = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> val x = df.schema.treeString
x: String =
"root
 |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
"

scala> val y = df.printSchema
root
 |-- value: integer (nullable = false)

y: Unit = ()
```

Comment: thanks a lot , its there "df.schema().treeString()" but need to check if works as expected.  One more thing , is there any spark Notebook available for java ? like we have databricks for Scala ? i.e. for spark programming

Comment: AFIK there is none.But I could be wrong. You can track this feature request in case you are interested.
https://forums.databricks.com/questions/12066/feature-request-add-notebook-support-for-java-repl.html

Comment: thank you ..submitted https://forums.databricks.com/questions/17916/feature-request-why-notebook-does-not-support-for.html

Answer (score 2):

`printSchema` method already prints the schema to the console without returning it in any form. You can simply call the method and redirect console output somewhere else. There are other workarounds like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600328/how-to-redirect-scala-spark-dataset-show-to-log4j-logger).