# Kill process started by org.apache.commons.executor

Tags: java, apache, testng, apache-commons, apache-commons-exec

I started execution of a testng.xml through apache commons executor libarary by following code:

```
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler;
        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog;
        final Executor executor;

        resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
        watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(-1L);
        executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(new LogOutputStream() {

        @Override
        protected void processLine(final String line, @SuppressWarnings("unused") int level) {
           Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") > -1) {

                        textArea.append(line+"\n");
                    } else if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf("warn") > -1) {
                        textArea.append(line+"\n");
                    } else {
                        textArea.append(line+"\n");


                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }));

    executor.setExitValue(1);
    executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
    executor.execute(cl, resultHandler);
```

But I want to give a stop button to stop this process. I tried :

```
executor.getWatchdog().destroyProcess();
```

But this destroys only the watchdog . However the testng.xml I started keeps on running in the background. I want to destroy the process that I gave in the command . 
Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need to use apache executor to spin off a `TestNG` suite execution ? You are better off using the TestNG apis directly in your java code no ? Also please show us what does `cl` a.k.a your `CommandLine` look like.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I want to send the console output directly to a Jframe textarea which I am not sure is possible through TestNG APIs . Also I want to run it as a different thread so that the main application does not hangs. The command c1 is: cmd.exe /k cd "D:\MyProject" && D: && java -cp D:\MyProject\Utilities\*;D:\MyProject\bin org.testng.TestNG D:\MyProject\testng.xml

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind why your solution is not killing the JVM that was spawned is perhaps because you are invoking `cmd.exe` and from within that is where you are probably spawning the JVM. So when you invoke `destroyProcess()` I believe its `cmd.exe` that is getting killed but not `java.exe`.

You should try changing your command line to something like below:

```
java -cp D:\MyProject\Utilities*;D:\MyProject\bin org.testng.TestNG D:\MyProject\testng.xml
```

Here's a solution that does not make use of Apache commons executor for doing this, but manages everything within a single JVM and also provides for a way to retrieve the output and error output from TestNG.

This solution makes use of the TestNG APIs.

The main test runner, that uses TestNG to run tests, in a different thread looks like below

```
import org.testng.TestNG;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class SimpleTestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.err.println("***Main Thread running in Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "]***");
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        WorkerThread thread = new WorkerThread(SampleTestClass.class);
        List<Future<ExecutionResults>> allResults = service.invokeAll(Collections.singletonList(thread));
        service.shutdown();
        ExecutionResults result = allResults.get(0).get();
        System.err.println("******Printing the TestNG output******");
        System.err.println(result);
        System.err.println("**************************************");
    }

    public static class WorkerThread implements Callable<ExecutionResults> {
        private Class<?>[] classes;

        WorkerThread(Class<?>... classes) {
            this.classes = classes;
        }

        @Override
        public ExecutionResults call() throws Exception {
            System.err.println("***Worker Thread running in Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "]***");
            TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
            ExecutionResults results;
            testNG.setVerbose(2);
            ConsoleCapturer capturer = new ConsoleCapturer();
            testNG.setTestClasses(classes);
            try {
                capturer.start();
                testNG.run();
            } finally {
                ConsoleCapturer.CapturedData data = capturer.stop();
                results = new ExecutionResults(data, testNG.getStatus());
            }
            return results;
        }
    }

    public static class ExecutionResults {
        private ConsoleCapturer.CapturedData data;
        private int status;

        public ExecutionResults(ConsoleCapturer.CapturedData data, int status) {
            this.data = data;
            this.status = status;
        }

        public ConsoleCapturer.CapturedData getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ExecutionResults{" +
                    "data=" + getData() +
                    ", status=" + getStatus() +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

The utility class that re-directs all output and error contents to a thread, so that they can be redirected to anywhere, looks like below :

This class is mostly borrowed code from the solution [Redirect console output to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java) with some improvisations.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

/**
 * This class is an improvisation of the solution provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30665299/679824
 */
public class ConsoleCapturer {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream baosOutput, baosError;
    private PrintStream previousOut, previousError;
    private boolean capturing;

    public void start() {
        if (capturing) {
            return;
        }

        capturing = true;
        previousOut = System.out;
        previousError = System.err;
        baosOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        baosError = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStreamCombiner(previousOut, baosOutput)));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStreamCombiner(previousError, baosError)));
    }

    public CapturedData stop() {

        if (!capturing) {
            return new CapturedData();
        }

        System.setOut(previousOut);
        System.setErr(previousError);

        String output = baosOutput.toString();
        String error = baosError.toString();

        try {
            baosOutput.close();
            baosError.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        baosOutput = null;
        previousOut = null;
        capturing = false;

        return new CapturedData(output, error);
    }

    private static class OutputStreamCombiner extends OutputStream {
        private OutputStream[] outputStreams;

        OutputStreamCombiner(OutputStream... outputStreams) {
            this.outputStreams = outputStreams;
        }

        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            for (OutputStream os : outputStreams) {
                os.write(b);
            }
        }

        public void flush() throws IOException {
            for (OutputStream os : outputStreams) {
                os.flush();
            }
        }

        public void close() throws IOException {
            for (OutputStream os : outputStreams) {
                os.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class CapturedData {
        private String output;
        private String error;

        CapturedData() {
            this("", "");
        }

        public CapturedData(String output, String error) {
            this.output = output;
            this.error = error;
        }

        public String getError() {
            return error;
        }

        public String getOutput() {
            return output;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CapturedData{" +
                    "output='" + getOutput() + '\'' +
                    ", error='" + getError() + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

The test class used looks like below

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        System.err.println("This goes into the error console");
        System.out.println("This goes into the console");
    }
}
```

The output looks like below

```
***Main Thread running in Thread [1]***
***Worker Thread running in Thread [11]***
This goes into the console
This goes into the error console
PASSED: testMethod

===============================================
    Command line test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

******Printing the TestNG output******
ExecutionResults{data=CapturedData{output='This goes into the console
PASSED: testMethod

===============================================
    Command line test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

', error='This goes into the error console
'}, status=0}
**************************************

Process finished with exit code 0
```