# Trying to read the console from past prints Java

Tags: java, io

I am trying to print out a message based on whether or not a previous specific message was printed. Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static Runnable getRunnable() {

    return () -> {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread");

    };
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    new Thread(getRunnable()).start();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scanner.next();

        if (name.equals("Hello from a thread")) {
            System.out.println("Hi!");
    } else {
            System.out.println("That's not nice");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that Scanner is probably no the solution here, but whenever I try something else like `System.console.readLine()`, which is probably also not correct, it prints out a `NullPointerException`. What am I supposed to use here to read previous output?

UPDATE: Hey, I tried it again but it didn't work out... not sure why again. Here's my updated code

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
public static PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
public static PrintStream old = System.out;

public static Runnable getRunnable() {
    System.out.println("Hello from a thread");
    return () -> {
        System.setOut(ps);
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread");
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    new Thread(getRunnable()).start();

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Somethings wrong!");
    }

    System.out.flush();
    System.setOut(old);
    if (baos.toString().equals("Hello from a thread")) {
        System.out.println("Hello other thread!");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java

Answer (score 1):

## `System.out` is not `System.in`

`System.out` is the standard output stream, which usually prints to console. `System.in` is the standard input stream, which usually is taken from console. You can do `setOut`, `setIn`, and `setErr` to change the I/O streams, so for your case, you would need to redirect `in` to read from a source and `out` to output to that source. You may consider using an ArrayList to store and retrieve the output / input:

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    public void write(int b) {
        list.add(b);
    }
}));
System.setIn(new InputStream() {
    public int read() {
        if (list.size() == 0) return -1;
        return list.remove(0);
    }
});
```

(Note that for various reasons, you probably want to do `setErr` so you can still output things properly.)

You can try a working example of this [here](https://tio.run/##dZDBTsMwDIbP7VOYnVLQqnFlbBIHJCaBQBo3xCFrvS0jTarEXTdQn724oRUVEpdY/mz/v@ODPMqpLdEc8o@2VUVpHcGBYapsejmPx6QipTsWl9VGqwwyLb2HJ6kMfMVRDz1J4nC0KoeCS2JNTpnd2ztIt/MJ0N7Z2sP9KcOSlA2j0VYZqeFRebpdGcIduiVozmABBmu4c06eQ3Upkjn3r8@esEg90nNFomt5YRNiK5RFyJmX1QCSYDJsGFarnSIUPAObvhp1hqnMc7EJHlHDT5P88VuZIL8y/6l3kozzAUdqCyJIe/WJTBcLmCXcQpUzML0OVlGfhj6HhT2imI23GC1hK0rL7rfaiMkDam0vJj/1TBqDDnwff27XU9FPKzPWQud@tV73CIQnglr6G5jA1aCUGqYiXKKJm7b9Bg)