# How to read spring boot console output

Tags: java, spring

How do I append spring boot's console output to a string builder?

I already have a `StringBuilder` variable, in which I would like to append the console output and still log to console.

Comment: I have come across this question and found a good explanation on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java).

Comment: Thanks for that @abhijeetsakhalkar. I had googled around but wasn't lucky